# What does Genesis 8:21 promise and why?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, korban, parashat-noach

[JPS Bereshith/Genesis 8:21](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8172/showrashi/true#v21) And the Lord smelled the pleasant aroma, and the Lord said to Himself, "I will no longer curse the earth because of man, for the imagination of man's heart is evil from his youth, and I will no longer smite all living things as I have done.

Does it mean:

- no more judicial global extinctions by flood (narrowest view)
- no more universal flood
- no more judicial global extinctions of any kind
- no more judicial global extinctions of any kind - sacrifice instead

Does the juxtaposition of the gratification of Noah's offering with the pronouncement of "never again" suggest that the plan will be a temple with a sacrificial/priestly function for Israel rather than dealing directly with mankind somewhat anthropomorphically inspired by Noah?

Comment: It means that [ice ages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_age), which always end in a large-scale sea-level rise, giving birth to various [deluge myths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_myth), such as the [Biblical Noah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_flood_narrative), the [Greek Atlantis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantis), or the [Babylonian Gilgamesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh), are far apart, and that [the *last* one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Glacial_Period) might also have been just that.